# How do you add thumbnail images to RSS feed?

Tags: xml, rss, media, feed

How do you add thumbnail images to an RSS feed?  I've tried `<image>` but that does not work inside an `<item>` element.  I've heard something about using `<media:thumbnail>`, but I don't know the restrictions, like the maximum height, maximum width, and file type.  Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Send us your feed url and we'll be able to provide the exact code you need to put in there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by using `<media:thumbnail url="" width="" height=""/>`

Don't forget to add the Yahoo XMLNS!